# How to change hash keys from `Symbol`s to `String`s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to "easily" / "quickly" change hash keys from `Symbol`s to `String`s. That is, from `{:one => "Value 1", :two => "Value 2", ...}` to `{"one" => "Value 1", "two" => "Value 2", ...}`.

How can I make that by using less code as possible?

Comment: If you used HashWithIndifferentAccess instead of a hash, then that would be done automatically for you.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

simply call `stringify_keys` (or `stringify_keys!`)

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/stringify_keys

Comment: `deep_stringify_keys` is recursive, but I believe it's only in Rails 4: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/deep_stringify_keys

Answer (score 21):

Use `stringify_keys`/`stringify_keys!` methods of the `Hash` class.

You can also use `some_hash.with_indifferent_access` to return a Hash instance where your key can be specified as symbols or as strings with no difference.

Answer (score 18):

`hash = hash.transform_keys(&:to_s)` turns all keys from symbols into strings.

More here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys

This was added in ruby 2.5: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13583

Comment: This won't do deep transform'ing

Comment: But it will do shallow transforming without Rails.

Answer (score 15):

`stringify_keys` is nice, but only available in Rails.
Here's how I would do it in a single line, with zero dependencies:

```rb
new_hash = Hash[your_hash.collect{|k,v| [k.to_s, v]}]
```

This works on Ruby 1.8.7 and up.
If you are working with Ruby 2.1, you can do:

```rb
new_hash = a.collect{|k,v| [k.to_s, v]}.to_h
```

Note that this solution is not recursive, nor will it handle "duplicate" keys properly. eg. if you have `:key` and also `"key"` as keys in your hash, the last one will take precedence and overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 5):

### stringify_keys from rails

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys

```
hash = { name: 'Rob', age: '28' }
hash.stringify_keys
# => { "name" => "Rob", "age" => "28" }
```

Answer (score 3):

there is a nice library that does the trick, the library is "facets/hash/rekey"
and the method is rekey!. Se my example below of how to use it. It is just a copy past of

```
> require 'facets/hash/rekey'
 => true
> a = {:one => "Value 1", :two => "Value 2"}
 => {:one=>"Value 1", :two=>"Value 2"} 
> a.rekey!(&:to_s)
 => {"one"=>"Value 1", "two"=>"Value 2"} 
> a
 => {"one"=>"Value 1", "two"=>"Value 2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 new_hash = Hash.new
 your_hash.each{ |k,v| new_hash[k.to_s] = v }
```

new_hash will be same as your_hash but with string keys

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the key from symbols to strings explicitly:
`hash = hash.map { |k, v| [k.to_s, v] }.to_h`

Answer (score 0):

I came here to see if there was something better than:

```
JSON.parse(hash.to_json)
```

But I think I'll stick with what I have.

Comment: Be careful with this strategy as it will also turn any values that are symbols into strings.