# Convert symbols to string when serializing with Oj.dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, hash

**Problem Summary:** I am attempting to serialize a hash to JSON using the [Oj gem](https://github.com/ohler55/oj). It seems that Oj does not automatically convert the symbol keys of the hash to strings. I am wondering if Oj has an option to "stringify" during serialization?

This is an example of my hash:

```
example_hash = 
 {:id=>1234,
  :asset_number=>"1234-5678",
  :latitude=>34.78495,
  :longitude=>-92.12899,
  :last_tracking_record_id=>123456789,
  :bearing=>42,
  :threat_level=>:severe}
```

And the above is rendered like so:

```
render json: Oj.dump(example_hash)
```

The resulting JSON unfortunately has keys that look exactly like the above, meaning I would need to access elements in JavaScript like so: `response[:asset_number]`. Since the client-side code was implemented months ago, and have only now added Oj, I would prefer to find a way to stringify the keys during serialization server-side.

Oj has an option called `symbol_keys`, which is a boolean, however setting it to either `true` or `false` seems to have no effect in this regard.

The only solution I have found thus far is to use `with_indifferent_access` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549699/877472), however in some cases I have arrays of hashes; while I can technically invoke that method for each hash in that array, given that Oj is meant to speed up Json serialization I would prefer to find a way to do this with Oj itself. Ultimately, I wonder if there is an option or setting in Oj that will perform this *during* serialization.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While I was writing the question, I was able to find the answer. Since I cannot find any other answers on StackOverflow relating to this issue (specifically with regards to the Oj gem), I will keep this post in the hopes it will help others in my situation.

According to [this previously discussed issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ohler55/oj/issues/54), setting the option `mode` to `:compat` will indeed convert the symbols to strings. So my render line now looks like this:

```
render json: Oj.dump(example_hash, mode: :compat)
```

According to the [Oj documentation for `default_options`](http://ohler.com/oj/Oj.html#default_options-class_method), `:compat` mode is defined as follows:

> ...compatible with other systems. It will serialize any Object but will
>   check to see if the Object implements a to_hash() or to_json() method.
>   If either exists that method is used for serializing the Object. The
>   to_hash() is more flexible and produces more consistent output so it
>   has a preference over the to_json() method. If neither the to_json()
>   or to_hash() methods exist then the Oj internal Object variable
>   encoding is used.

So if I am interpreting that correctly, it seems this solution works because it is ultimately using the `to_json` method of the `Hash` class.

I am uncertain whether I have affected performance (either positively or negatively), but at least it saves me from having to manually invoke `with_indifferent_access` or `to_json` in the case of an array.

**Update**

In regards to performance, [cmwright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657097/cmwright) did some benchmarking, and came up with these results:

```
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
json        13.990000   0.250000  14.240000 ( 14.257051)
oj default   3.260000   0.230000   3.490000 (  3.491028)
oj compat    3.360000   0.240000   3.600000 (  3.593109)
------------------------------------ total: 21.330000sec

                 user     system      total        real
json        13.740000   0.240000  13.980000 ( 13.992641)
oj default   3.020000   0.230000   3.250000 (  3.248077)
oj compat    3.060000   0.230000   3.290000 (  3.286443)
```

Seems like the `compat` option is at least on par with the default `Oj` options, and significantly more efficient than plain 'ol `to_json`.

This is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/cmwright/17381202ec8d4bcb8a2a) containing the benchmark code.

Comment: I just did some benchmarking to make sure that compat mode wouldn't affect performance and was pleasantly surprised for my usecase. I used a hash (string => int) with 10,000 keys and got the following results with Benchmark.bmbm (can't seem to format in these comments): json        14.550000   0.270000  14.820000 ( 14.855023)
oj default   3.420000   0.250000   3.670000 (  3.684655)
oj compat    3.500000   0.260000   3.760000 (  3.758900)

Comment: @cmwright Ah very nice. I was quite certain after a while that there were no performance problems, but I never got around to doing any actual benchmarks. That's great to know. This question seems to be getting more views than I expected, so would you mind if I add your data to the answer (with proper credit of course)?

Comment: Yeah absolutely go for it. I can post a gist of the code I used next time im at a computer

Comment: @cmwright Excellent, thanks! Answer updated. I guess `compat` seems to have a very small effect on performance, but the difference seems to be practically negligible (assuming its not a fluke).

Answer (score 3):

Using the generate method gives you the same output.

```rb
Oj.generate({a: `test`})
```