# Nested Liquid Templates in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, liquid

According to Sinatra docs you pass liquid objects into a liquid template like so

`liquid :index, :locals => { :title => "My Sinatra App"}`

for rendering in a template like

`{{title}}`

This seems to break with nested objects though, for instance

`liquid :index, :locals => { :foo => { :bar => "baz" }}`

Doesn't let me refer to the value of bar in the liquid template like

`{{foo.bar}}`

Is there some specific way to build nested liquid objects for passing into a view? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dealing with this same issue, and I discovered that if you use symbols to define subkeys in the locals hash, you don't get the behavior you might expect.  In other words:

```
liquid :index, :locals => { :foo => { :bar => "baz" }}
```

will not make `{{ foo.bar }}` do what you expect.  What you want is:

```
liquid :index, :locals => { :foo => { "bar" => "baz" }}
```

This will make `{{ foo.bar }}` substitute with the value `baz` as you expect.

Given this behavior, this may be a useful/relevant follow-on SO post:

[How to change hash keys from `Symbol`s to `String`s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549554/how-to-change-hash-keys-from-symbols-to-strings)